# hibernate lazy loading of collection

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I m not very versed in Hibernate and have following query:

Consider two classes:

```
public class Ticket{

  private List<Attachement> attachmentList=new ArrayList<Attachment>();
  ...
}

public class Attachment{
   private String fileName;
   private bytes[] fileData;
}
```

*consider a scenario:*

user opens a ticket to see its details.Along with ticket details list of all attachements  related to that ticket will also shown up(i mean only names of attachments). user will click on a filename to download that attachment.

While displaying details of ticket I do not want to fetch the related attachments  **data** until user click on their fienames to download them. (I want to show their **names only**)

With lazy loading, loading of  attachements can be deferred but how to fetch their filenames ('*fileName*' attribute of class Attachment) earlier only but not the '*fileData*'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom query to load just the names of the attachments.  In your application, you should have some sort of `TicketService` with a `loadTicket` method on it.  In that method, you should load the ticket (and only the ticket), and then just the names of the Attachments that are attached to the ticket.

Return that data to the UI.  When the user clicks an attachment name, you can then load the full Attachment.

Answer (score 1):

That would be difficult to do using simple object load without explicit querying. I would suggest to create custom finder methods (may be using using native sql queries). Fetch the IDs and Filename first, display them, when the user clicks on the FileName, u have id, fetch the Attachment from that.